# Appgyver steroids and Ionic directives

Tags: ionic-framework, steroids

It is not clear to me how to "build" a UI with Appgyver Steroids. It looks like it uses only the CSS side of Ionic to render views, and not the javascript side. 
This way is not possible to design UI with Ionic angular directives.
Am I wrong?
So my question is: which is the right way to design views in a Steroids app? Just by HTML and Ionic CSS classes? Is there a guide, maybe with example?
Is it possible to simply include Ionic javascript and use its directives? Some drawbacks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Merituuli from AppGyver here.

We don't use the angular directives of Ionic because Steroids has methods to use native tabs and drawer elements, thus making the solution Ionic made unnecessary.

If you however want to include the Ionic angular directives you can do that by downloading the files you want to use from http://code.ionicframework.com/#, adding them to the `/vendor` folder and including them in your `application.html`.

If you need guides, tutorials and examples of using Steroids tabs, modals etc: https://academy.appgyver.com/categories/3-user-interface-and-design/contents

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any updated documentation, cuz your documentation is 3 to 4 months old and no more applicable. Am stuck in a lot of problems but can't find any example code or explanation.